# Not getting equal values when calculating AUC for two normal distributions

Tags: r

I know it is a bit tricky, but I hope you are up for it.

Given two normal curves, I am doing calculations on the AUC between the overlap between the means of the 2 curves.

First I calculate the x-value for the intercept of the two curves like so:

```
gaussIsect = function(mu1,mu2,sd1,sd2){
    sd12 = sd1**2
    sd22 = sd2**2
    sqdi = sd12-sd22
    x1 = (mu2 * sd12 - sd2*( mu1*sd2 + sd1*sqrt( (mu1-mu2)**2 + 2*sqdi * log(sd1/sd2) ) )) / sqdi
    x2 = (mu2 * sd12 - sd2*( mu1*sd2 - sd1*sqrt( (mu1-mu2)**2 + 2*sqdi * log(sd1/sd2) ) )) / sqdi
    return(c(x1,x2))
}
```

Then I calculate the combined AUC and find the x-values, which halfes this:

```
gaussSplitOlap = function(mu1,mu2,sd1,sd2){
    # Make sure that mu1 < mu2
    if( mu1 > mu2 ){
        tmp = c(mu1,mu2)
        mu1 = tmp[2]
        mu2 = tmp[1]
        tmp = c(sd1,sd2)
        sd1 = tmp[2]
        sd2 = tmp[1]
    }
    # Get the intersect of the two normal curves
    isct = gaussIsect(mu1=mu1,mu2=mu2,sd1=sd1,sd2=sd2)
    # and make sure we have the intersect between the means
    isct = isct[which(mu1 < isct & isct < mu2)]
    # Calculate left curve AUC, i.e. from isct to inf
    a1 = 1-pnorm(isct,mean=mu1,sd=sd1)
    # Calculate right curve AUC, i.e. from -inf to isct
    a2 = pnorm(isct,mean=mu2,sd=sd2)
    # Calculate the total area
    A  = a1 + a2
    # Calculate the left curve x-value, which halfes the total area
    v1 = qnorm(1-A/2,mean=mu1,sd=sd1)
    # Calculate the right curve x-value, which halfes the total area
    v2 = qnorm(A/2,mean=mu2,sd=sd2)
    # Create and return list of results
    results = list(isct=isct,A=A,v1=v1,v2=v2)
    return(results)
}
test = gaussSplitOlap(mu1 = 10,sd1 = 0.9,mu2 = 12,sd2 = 0.6)
print(test)
```

If I run this, then test is

```
$isct
[1] 11.09291

$A
[1] 0.1775984

$v1
[1] 11.21337

$v2
[1] 11.19109
```

I cannot figure out, why v1 != v2? As I see it, it is the same value calculated from two different points of reference?

Comment: I don't get your assertion about the same value (quantile) as they are computed from different parameters with different means and standard deviation...

Comment: @Tensibai Maybe I was not completely clear about the setup. Given two normal distributions N1(mu1,sd1) and N2(mu2,sd2), for which mu1 < mu2 and sd1 != sd2. If we then plot N1 and N2, then I calculate the x-value for the curve intersection between the means. I then use this value to calculate the total area under the overlap of the curves between the means. Next I half this area and calculate the corresponding x-value relative to the left curve 'v1' and likewise for the right curve 'v2'. Unless I am completely mistaken, this should be the same value?

Comment: According to your description, in an ideal world with infinite decimal, yes. but in computing floatting points numbers are subject to limitations, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)

Comment: (I can't confirm or infirm you maths are ok, so I trust you they are :p, only possibility I see in this case is deviation from floating points arithmetic)

Comment: Or maybe I'm totaly wrong but your computed AREA is perhaps not equally split around x (may worth a drawing to illustrate what I mean here)

Comment: When I find the x-value for the intersection of the curves 'isct', I solve analytically f1(x) = f2(x), where f1 and f2 are the density functions for N1 and N2 (See function gaussIsect()). Then for the left curve, I calculate the area 'a1' from 'isct' to Inf and for the right curve I calculate the area 'a2' from -Inf to 'isct'. Lastly I set A = a1 + a2 and calculate the x-value at A/2. It is this x-value which unexpectedly is not the same for both the left and the right curve. You may be right about the floating point - It has crossed my mind, but I think the difference is rather substantial.

Comment: I may be wrong but I'll try to express my though with simple value, if a1=1 and a2=2. A=3, the X value for A/2 relative to each curve sounds unrelated to the intersection in my mind.

Comment: (unless the curves are absolutely symmetric on both side of x)

Comment: I need the intersection to calculate the area under the overlap. For the left curve (f1), the area under the right curve (f2) extends from the intersection to Inf. For the right curve (f2) the area under the left curve (f1) extends from -Inf to the intersection. The intersection is exactly at f1(x) = f2(x). If we move to the left of the intersection, then f1(x) > f2(x) and if we move the right of the intersection, then f1(x) < f2(x). Hence the intersection is the point which defines the overlap of f1 and f2 between mu1 and mu2 (mu1<mu2). Symmetri only occurs, when sd1=sd2.